# How can I reset the package cache on just one package with Swift Package Manager

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

There's a "Reset Package Caches" option in the menu in Xcode, but that resets them all, which takes a while.  Is it possible to just reset one package cache?

Comment: Remove and add ?

Answer (score 59):

To reset the cache for a single package:

- Navigate to `~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/repositories` and deleting the **folder and lock file** related to the package
- Then, in Xcode, run `File-->Swift Packages-->Reset Package Caches`

You can also try the solution recommended here to reset the entire cache (thanks @Bao Lei):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72838880/1099193

Comment: Both ~/Library/Caches/org.swiftpm/repositories and $BUILD_DIR/SourcePackages/repositories contains almost same git repositories.

Comment: This doesn't completely reset on Xcode 13.3.
What solved the issue for me was right click on package in Xcode and press Update package. Somehow after all clearing it was grabbing it from some cache which I haven't figured out how can be reset

Comment: For Xcode 13.4 what solved this issue for me was to, in Xcode, select menu  File/Packages/Reset Package Caches

Comment: In my case I also need to clear ~/Library/org.swift.swiftpm as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/72838880/1099193

Comment: Deleting the single repository solved it for me. My issue was a package with a deleted tag that was re-used for another commit. SPM ended up having cache folders for both commits. Removing both and resetting fixed it. Thanks!