# Xcode: how to update a package to the branch last commit via SPM

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm working on a Swift package and on an app using it, with Xcode 14.2

Due to incremental updates, I reference my package from my app with the branch I'm working on (for example: `feature/current-dev`)

Then I push a new commit on the package repository. How do I get this very last commit in the app?

Here's what I tried:

- right click on my package, Update package *=> doesn't do anything*
- right click on "Package Dependencies", update to latest package versions *=> doesn't do anything*
- right click on "Package Dependencies", "reset Package Caches" (takes forever when you also use big packages as Firebase) *=> new commit still missing*
- manually deleted package caches (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68876107/127493), then update again *=> commit still missing*
- removing the package from the app, waiting, adding the package again *=> Nope!*
- ...

At this point I feels Xcode is trolling me. Is this the expected SPM behaviour? How to get the last commit?

Comment: Have you tried to close XCode and remove DerivedData? Then in theory XCode will reload packages.

Comment: It may work but that's not an acceptable workflow to do such a simple task. I'll try it next time by the way